# USB keyboard hit and miss as to whether it will work on boot-up

Tags: 12.04, usb, keyboard, startup

I am new to Ubuntu. Have installed 12.04 on a slave drive while I migrate.

Usually booting into Ubuntu goes without a hitch but recently I often find I am unable to use the keyboard, and log-in using the on-screen KB.

Sometimes if I remove the USB jack & re-connect it will start working again but not always.

I do have an old PS/2 KB which I am using at the moment but.......has anyone any ideas on how to get the USB KB reliably connected?

Thanks   Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share a dmesg log? /var/log/dmesg.  It would be most helpful to see a log from when the keyboard was not found at boot, but usable after disconnect & reconnect.

Comment: keyboard still inactive so can't. I'll try plugging it into a USB2 port to see if more reliable. Thanks for the tip the dmesg log seems quite useful :-) Thanks